# How to use Bitnami Memcached between my Azure WebApp and MySQL DB, both being PaaS service?

Tags: mysql, azure, memcached, bitnami, azure-database-mysql

I am having an application running under Microsoft Azure WebApp service which is connected to a MySQL Database as a service. Now, I want to use Memcache for my Database, so that database query can speed up, based on excessive application load. For that, I am using Bitnami Memcached cluster with multiple instances. Now, I just need to know, what all I need to configure for memcached to perform proper caching for my DB. Do anything need to be changed on application code level as well?
Let me know, if my question is anyhow unclear or for any further clarification. Thanks.